# Unable to install Oracle 11g in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, oracle11g

I am trying to install Oracle version win32_11gR1_database_111070, I am getting an error as Operating system does not  supported at the time of environment checkup. Is there any way to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a blog posting explaining with pictures how to do it: http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/11/27/oracle-11g-on-windows-7/

To summarize it, you check the "operating system requirements" checkbox yourself, and it will display as "User Verified", after which you can keep going.

Answer (score 0):

This is specially for the window7 users who are stuggling in installing 11g release oracle

Most of the people finding hard to install and will be getting common error like "`/WFMLRSVCA.App.ear` "file not found  is because the copied file from file win64_11gR2_database_2of2" is not copied in the proper file

The below steps is require to install your 11g database

1. copy first 4 files from  `win64_11gR2_database_2of2`"
2. Open "`Win64_11gR2_database_2of2`
3. Then open the following folders `database/stage/components`
4. so on copy the copied files from 11R2 to the above mentioned folders

and it works alas i would be able to install the `11gR2` ...